# Obtener ruta de donde se ejecuto el archivo jar

Tags: java, eclipse

Hola estoy desarrollando una aplicacion, que se ejecutara desde una USB, pero como la ruta absoluta de una USB puede variar dependiendo el equipo, ya sea que este en `D:\`  o `F:\` ect, ect. necesito saber como obtener la ubicacion de donde se ejecuto el jar.

al principio lo puse de la siguiente forma

File archivo_ejemplo = new File("D:\ejemplo.txt");

pero ya se imaginan que paso cuando lo ejecute en otro ordenador.
Alguna solucion?

Comment: Aqui tienes un ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file#320595

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()).getPath();
```

Con esta setencia obtienes la ruta de tu jar (incluido el propio jar). Eliminas de la ruta el jar y ya tienes la carpeta.

NOTA: reemplaza MyClass por el nombre de tu clase.

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file)